# Bind A Table in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a datatable,i am assigning this datatable in viewbag like viewbag.data = datatable; now I want to bind a table on cshtml page by this viewbag.data. please tell me how can I achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

In your page you can get the datatable and use it like in this example:

```
// Cast is useful to work with the object.
@{ var data = (DataTable)ViewBag.Data; }
@foreach(DataRow row in data.Rows) {
  // Write your html code here. 
}
```

Comment: thanks ,I have done it,but when I am passing datatable like  Html.RenderPartial("_SearchResultDisplayOne", ((System.Data.DataTable)ViewBag.datatable)); than I am getting this type of error : The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.DataTable', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ADE.Business.UserModels.IRequest]'.

Comment: This problem is not related to my answer. You are trying to pass a DataTable to a View that accept only a IEnumerable of IRequest, the message is very clear.

Answer (score 0):

using Viewbag is nice for rapid iteration but you should create  a viewmodel and populate the Data property of the model before passing it to the view. You will then have a typesafe way of accessing the Data property in the view like

```
  @Model.Data
```